# Comment template in VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, comments, xml-comments

I have inherited an API which doesn't have proper comments, and I am working on changing that.

Anyone know if there is some sort of mechanism to add a default XML comments to all the members of a class or an assembly?
(I remember seeing something like that on a webcast and I think he might have used PowerShell script to achieve that.)

This way I can avoid lots of repetitive steps, and have everything in place to go and start writing just the comments.

Anyone has any better suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) is pretty fantastic for XML documentation, although you'll need to purchase a copy to generate automatic documentation for all classes/members. The free version allows you to right click (or use a hotkey) on class or member and it will generate the documentation.

Comment: @Ryan S: Do you have the licensed version? Anything in particular you like about it?

Comment: @Voodoo, Unfortunately no, I use the free version. You could try asking on the [GhostDoc forums](http://community.submain.com/forums/30/ShowForum.aspx) and see if you can get some opinions there.

Comment: @Ryan S: The pro version comes with 14 days trial so I guess I can try it out myself.

Answer (score 3):

I've found GhostDoc to be pretty good.

Once you've run it over your code you then simply add details where required.

http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx